# Download image on click - Using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to add a download image on click function for a website. I'm attempting to use PHP to do it as as far as I am aware, there is no way to do it in HTML without it linking to another blank page and then right click save as, which is not what I want. 
I found this code on here and wish to adapt it, but I'm concerned of breaking it because my understanding of PHP is not vast. Also, I need to use this on multiple files, but the PHP I'm using suggests you can only use it in one file, meaning I may need numerous PHP files, one for each image download?

Anyway, I'm not sure, but I could do with some help adapting the code if anyone is able to assist me?
The images are in the following directory directly from the site:
/img/bkg/img1.jpg
This also follows into img2-5 also.

Anyway, here is the code used in the main file to show the image and link to the PHP file download:

```
<a href="download.php?file=path/<?=$row['img1.jpg']?>">
    <img src="img/bkg/img1.jpg" alt="CWP - Wallpaper 1" width="1056" height="600"/>
</a>
```

Here is the code I need to adapt for these files and the correct directories:

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

download_file($file);

function download_file( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

I am sorry if the above is a silly question, but I would rather seek help in this than break it over and over. I am unsure where I am replacing files and directories etc. etc. and I would like to get it right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The filename is passed in the querystring, just change the filename for each link, and it should work fine?

Comment: You really should try to do this yourself or at least understand what the script is doing: For example, without input validation, you should definitely not use this script, if someone hits your server with `download.php?file=../../../etc/passwd` you could have big problems.

Comment: About your question, do you want to download multiple files with one click or just have multiple downloads on one page?

Comment: I want to download one file, with one click, but there are mutliple images to click, therefore click img1.jpg, you get img1, img2.jpg get img2 etc. etc. 
As for understanding it, I've got a very basic understand of it reading through but I'm no expert on PHP, I've been learning recently but I'm jumping in the deep end here. I would avoid this but I have a deadline to meet and it is important to try and get this working with it - Once more, all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your script will handle multiple downloads on one page just fine, you can add as many:

```
<a href="download.php?file=path/<?=$row['img1.jpg']?>">
```

to the page as you like. Each time a link is clicked, the script will run and process the download according to the information you sent to it (`file=path/<?=$row['img1.jpg']?>` in the example).

However, this script has no input validation whatsoever so people can request system file by issuing requests like `download.php?file=../../../etc/passwd`.

To solve that I would get rid of the path in the query string (you can append that again in php, it's not anybody's business) and use something like a regular expression to check if the sent in variable contains illegal characters.

A simple example to illustrate:

```
if (preg_match('#[^\w.-]#', $_GET['file']))
{
  // if $_GET['file'] contains anything that is not a word character, a dot or a -
  die("invalid input");
}
else
{
  $file = 'path/' . $_GET['file'];
  // rest of your code
```

I would also remove the mime types you are not using, so only leave jpg or all image types.

Comment: Hi Jerone, thanks for the help :) I've added that to the code and removed the non-image related file types. 
This may seem stupid but it's where I'm running into problems. I am curious as to where exactly img1.jpg or other relevant image files go in the code. For example, where it say "file=path" in the HTML, is this a relation to a filepath I need to adapt to my files? Or is it a PHP command, or function? Also, in your code it say %_GET['file']; is that 'file' to be replaced with img1.jpg? Alongside similar at the top of the download.php document? Sorry if I seem useless, it's all new to me

Comment: @John McPherson Your links should be like: `download.php?file=the_image_you_want_to_download_here.jpg` and the path that you are adding in php should be the path where the image is stored, relative to the script you are running.

Comment: I adapted that to the following: 
<a href="img/bkg/img1.jpg?file=img/bkg/img1.jpg/<?=$row['img1.jpg']?>">
It works better now and understands where the image is, but it open the image in a new tab and then you have the standard right click option to download. I am unsure where I have gone wrong? John

Comment: @John McPherson Why are you adding `/<?=$row['img1.jpg']?>` at the end? And you should link to your script, not the image.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to replace it with so I replaced it with the image. I've changed that and I get the same result. This is possible the reason why... In the download.php file there are two sections that say the same thing: "$_GET['file'];" - Does this file need to be linked to my image? Or is it part of the PHP I am not following? There is also a $filepath attribute, I am unsure if I need to edit this anywhere?
Also, just to clarify, the link now looks like this:
<a href="img/bkg/img1.jpg?file=img/bkg/img1.jpg/<?=$row['download.php']?>">

Hope this is correct - thanks in advance, John :)